# using special characters in jquery html not showing correctly

Tags: jquery, html, encoding, utf

I'm using some special characters and they aren't displayed correctly, I don't know why!

I defined it like this :

```
var grade_value = 'Wešto izšamešđu';
```

and later I do this:

```
$('.list').append(
        "<p class='txt'>"+ grade_value + "</p>" 
);
```

This looks like this:
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sarc.png)

What could be the problem, here I can't encode using utf-8 or anything like that?

Comment: https://www.utexas.edu/learn/html/spchar.html

Comment: http://unicode-table.com/de/#control-character

Comment: @LaljiTadhani thank you very much for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try This....

```
var htmlVal=$("<div/>").html(grade_value).text();

$('.list').append(
        "<p class='txt'>"+htmlVal  + "</p>" 
);
```

Comment: I use like that but it isn't working , but I just didn't include the whole code. Thank you for your answer